# Im trying to get JSON data from js and receiving null in action class

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I'm getting JSON from client side. I want to send it through ajax. However, i'm getting null inside my action class.

my JSON string

```
{"data":[{"id":"","col":1,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},
         {"id":"","col":1,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},
         {"id":"","col":1,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},
         {"id":"","col":1,"row":4,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},
         {"id":"","col":1,"row":6,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},
         {"id":"","col":1,"row":5,"size_x":1,"size_y":1}
        ]
}
```

AJAX

```
var seats = {"data" : positions};

    var seatPosition = JSON.stringify(seats);

    console.log(seatPosition);  

    $.ajax({
        url: 'retrieve-seat',
        data: seatPosition,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="," />
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />

<package name="default" namespace="/"
    extends="json-default,struts-default">

    <action name="retrieve-seat" class="com.pointwest.apex.actions.ReadPositionAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="json"/>
    </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

Action.class

```
public class ReadPositionAction extends ActionSupport {

private List<Seat> data;


public List<Seat> getData() {
     System.out.println("Getter Call");
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Seat> data) {
     System.out.println("Setter Call");
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String execute() {
    System.out.println("action");
    try {
        System.out.println(data);


        System.out.println("Execute Method");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "SUCCESS";
}

}
```

The console log seems to display a correct format for JSON. Someone pls help me out thanks!

Comment: Since positions is a string don't stringify it. Pass positions to ajax directly.

Comment: I cannot pass positions directly because it contains an array of objects. positions came from .serialize(). @anmarti

Comment: Hi, I tried doing what you said. I still get null @anmarti

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **produce** JSON (Action -> JSP), the **`json` result** is enough.

If you need to **consume** JSON (JSP -> Action), you need to add the **Json Interceptor** to your stack.

From [the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-AcceptingJSON):

> **Accepting JSON**
>
> Your actions can accept incoming JSON if they are in package which
>   uses json interceptor or by adding reference to it as follow:
>
> ```
> @InterceptorRef(value="json")
> ```

Also note that the `json-default` package internally extends the `struts-default`, hence there is no need to extend both of them.

It should be:

```xml
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">

    <interceptor-stack name="jsonFromJspStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="json" />
    </interceptor-stack>


    <action name="retrieve-seat" class="com.pointwest.apex.actions.ReadPositionAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonFromJspStack"/>
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="json"/>
    </action>

</package>
```

Comment: I tried adding the interceptor like you said. It still returns null in action class.

I

Comment: I'm using struts2-json-plugin-2.3.14 and struts2-core same version

Comment: Then you have also other problems other the one solved by this answer

Comment: These are the only components i'm using as of now that's connected to the problem. the Seat bean/pojo is just a normal one complete with getters and setters too.

Comment: Have you removed the JSON.stringify ?

Comment: I tried passing positions which is an array of objects, I tried passing the stringified variable, unfortunately. I still get null

Comment: Try with  `data: {"data" : JSON.stringify(positions)},`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93473/discussion-between-dands-manuel-and-andrea-ligios).

Comment: @DandsManuel have you tried like in the last message in chat ? Can you try with STATIC json to see if it works ?